# Почему при записи QuerySet в переменную приходит пустота (django console)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

такая проблема: Делаю проект на django. В процессе проверяю некоторые вещи, используя интерактивную консоль django, и вот какую проблему я заметил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть объект `x` - Объект модели, у него есть связанные значения в модели `subscribeperiod_set`
Если я просто запущу

```py
x = Subscribe.objects.first() # Subscribe - Моя модель.
x.subscribeperiod_set.all().order_by('start')
```

То все отлично работает, я получаю `QuerySet` с нужными мне данными.

НО! Если  я всего лишь добавлю в начало второй строки `q =`  (сохраню этот QuerySet в переменную), то в ней окажется ПУСТОЙ QuerySet

```py
x = Subscribe.objects.first() # Subscribe - Моя модель.
q = x.subscribeperiod_set.all().order_by('start')
# q = <QuerySet []>
```

Почему я не могу сохранить querySet в переменную? так же очевидно не должно работать?

**P.S.** Как я заметил, такое поведение работает только со связаными через `имя_модели_set` Данными. Прямой запрос к другой таблице через `Модель.objects.all()` в переменную записывается без проблем

Сравнение query у QuerySet'ов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тогда сравните `str(q.query)` и `str(x.subscribeperiod_set.all().order_by('start').query)`

Comment: какую бд используете? и версию django

Comment: Использую Postgresql, django 2.2.19, В конец вопроса добавил скриншот, показывающий, что запросы в обоих случаях одинаковые

Comment: Попробуйте обновиться до Django==3.1.7, там у меня все исправно работает. Если не поможет - возможно проблема в интерпретаторе